# Responsive inline div bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my text within the div in center for xs size. It works for large size desktop but not for mobile devices Below is my code:

```
    <div class="row">
         <div style="background-color:lightblue;color:#33CAFF"
              class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3">STEP 1
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:#33CAFF;color:white"
              class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-5">2.SELECT VEHICLES & EXTRAS
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:white;color:gray"
              class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">STEP 3
         </div>
         <div style="background-color:white;color:gray"
              class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">STEP 4
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap version 3.3.7

Comment: Is center a custom class of yours?

Comment: Is your goal to have the text in the center of your `div` element, so it would look like the example here... [link](https://codepen.io/cowanjt/pen/prQLaG)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap might not support class do for this

You can add a custom class and write a little bit css like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;color:#33CAFF"
    class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3 xs-text-center">STEP 1
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:#33CAFF;color:white"
    class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-5 xs-text-center">2.SELECT VEHICLES & EXTRAS
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:white;color:gray"
    class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 xs-text-center">STEP 3
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:white;color:gray"
    class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 xs-text-center">STEP 4
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .xs-text-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```